# Having error, keeps saying Unknown File Extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, solidity

```
`"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Keith\WebstormProjects\flashbot\src\index.ts
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\Users\Keith\WebstormProjects\flashbot\src\in
dex.ts
←[90m    at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:71:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:105:42)←[39m
←[90m    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:31)←[39m
←[90m    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:17)←[39m
←[90m    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'←[39m
}
Process finished with exit code 1`
```

There is a lot of code and files for this project so I'm not sure what to tweak. It does, however, exist on github - https://github.com/flashbots/searcher-minter if you think you know the solution.

Comment: node doesn't know how to run typescript

Comment: `.ts` extensions are for typescript files. I think you might need to re-check if typescript is enabled in that project. Or if you have already run `yarn install` or `npm install` before running the project.

Answer (score 6):

You can't run the Typescript code by passing it to Node.js directly, Node.js doesn't provide native support for executing Typescript. The code has to be either compiled on-the-fly or precompiled. here are some recipes:

- To run a selected TypeScript file using `ts-node`:

  - Install ts-node using `npm i ts-node`.
  - Create a new **Node.js** run/debug configuration.
  - Add `--require ts-node/register` to the **Node parameters** field.
  - In the **JavaScript file** field add `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$`.
  - Save configuration.
  - Use it to run (or debug) a file that is currently opened in the editor or selected in the **Project** view. You can do that using the icons on the navigation bar or **Run...** action.

If you need to pass any additional parameters to `ts-node` (e.g. `--project tsconfig.json`), you can add them to the **Application parameter**s field in the run/debug configuration.

- To compile app with TypeScript and run a selected TypeScript file

  - Create a **Node.js** run/debug configuration.
  - In the **Before Launch** section, click **Add** and select **Compile TypeScript**.

    - Select `tsconfig.json`.
    - In the **JavaScript file** field you need to select the path to the compiled `.js` file.
    - If a compiled JavaScript lives next to its source, add `$FileRelativeDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js`
    - If files are saved in an output folder (preserving the folder structure), add the folder name before the pattern, e.g. `build/$FileRelativeDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js`
    - Save configuration.
    - Use it to run (or debug) a file that is currently opened in the editor or selected in the **Project** view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should adjust your tsconfig.json file and add a new `start` script, I think maybe the global script you trying to run can't find the `ts-node` module

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2018"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

###Add new start in your package.json

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
```